# Is there a more efficient JOIN than this to get correct output?

Tags: mysql, sql

The goal is to find all car rides that are pricier than train rides that take place either in the same state or outside the country (aka 'Non-UnitedStates')

This is the only way I could get it to work. I feel like it's inefficient. I wanted to do something like

However, this leads to the table outputting all modes of transportation. Any pointers to fix? Additionally, the question feels unclear. I don't know if "taken on a train in the same state or outside the country" means just the train is outside the country or the car ride can be too.

Comment: Sample data would help here.  Your first version might be fine, but note that you are using the old school join syntax.

Comment: To help with Sample data, this is a self join on a table that has TripId, State of Trip, TravelMode, and Cost. So for example TripID = 7, State is in CA (or 'Non-United'), Travel Mode = Car, and Cost = $2000. The self join helps me compare. However, as you've alluded to, this gets me my answer but it's highly dated.

Comment: The first query looks good to me. Now, what do you want as *efficient*? If it's high performance, some indexes can help. However you are probably **retrieving a significant amount of data**. It's probably bound to take some time.

Comment: I guess I'm just wondering if there's any way to condense it. It works for this specific problem but I'm wondering if there's any way to combine TripState from both lines, so I can both do comparing rows where the state is identical and comparing rows where train is out of country.

Comment: [Please edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67238970/edit) and include a few rows of sample data and expected result. You can [refer this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f186c4d81b2912406fe97c180c22349) to generate example structure & data. As for your expected result, please illustrate it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both conditions like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Trips C, Trips T
WHERE (C.TravelMode = 'Car' AND T.TravelMode = 'Train' AND C.Fare > T.Fare 
AND (C.TripState = T.TripState OR T.TripState = 'Non-US'));
```

Notice the `OR` condition is enclosed in parenthesis.

[**CHECK DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1438d94cdec59b6df0deace2132503bb)

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it is your "or" that is messing it up:
C.TripState = T.TripState OR T.TripState = 'Non-UnitedStates')